# Renewing \section command affects \subsection spacing

Tags: sectioning

If I use standard \section and \subsection commands I get the following normal behavior:

[image]

However, if I renew the section

```
% Custom sectioning style
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \begin{center}
        \oldsection*{#1}
    \end{center}
}

\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\oldsubsection*}
```

I get the following result

[image]

where the section headers appear to be ok, but the subsection header has lost the space above it that makes the separation between the header and the previous text. How can I avoid removing that space?.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

% Packages for maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

% Change padding of boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

% Custom title
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
}
\title{
    \textbf{Notas en Computación Cuántica}
}
\posttitle{
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \end{center}
}
\author{\large Jaime Señor}
\date{}

% Custom sectioning style
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \begin{center}
        \oldsection*{#1}
    \end{center}
}

\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\oldsubsection*}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Sobre el operador $\boldsymbol{U_f : \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \rangle \mapsto \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \oplus f(x) \rangle}$}

\subsection{Aplicación sobre una superposición de estados $\boldsymbol{\ket{-}}$ en el qubit objetivo}

Tiene mucha relevancia la aplicación de este tipo de operadores sobre un registro de la forma $(\ket{x} \otimes \ket{-})$:

\begin{equation*}
    U_f(\ket{x}\ket{-}) = U_f \left( \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \dfrac{U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{0} \right) - U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{1} \right)}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        f(x) = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\[15pt]
        f(x) = 1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{1} - \ket{0}}{\sqrt{2}} = - \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
    U_f(\ket{x} \ket{-}) = (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}\ket{-}
}
\end{equation*}

Lo bueno de usar el estado $\ket{-}$ es que el resultado de $f(x)$ queda codificado en el desplazamiento de fase $(-1)^{f(x)}$. Sin embargo, con el estado $\ket{+}$ no obtenemos ninguna utilidad de cara a implementar un algoritmo, porque $U_f(\ket{x}\ket{+})=\ket{x}\ket{+}$, y no aporta ninguna información sobre $f(x)$.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que según el resultado anterior, $\ket{-}$ es un autoestado de $U_f$ y se queda igual al pasar por el operador, por lo tanto podemos pasar de él al diseñar el algoritmo. A esto se le llama \textit{phase kickback}, y simplifica los algoritmos definiendo $U_f$ como

\begin{equation*}
    U_f: \ket{x} \mapsto (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}
\end{equation*}

\section{El algoritmo de Deutch}

Este algoritmo es uno de los primeros que se aprenden en computación cuántica y mola porque muestra por primera vez la gracia de la superposición cuántica.

\subsection{Enunciado del problema}

dfhgidufs

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a complete code, not just a snippet?

Comment: There it goes @Bernard :)

Comment: Actually, the old \subsection doesn't add a line either.  Since you aren't generating a table of centers, you might be better off creating a custom \section and \subsection from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\titleformat*`, from `titlesec`, it works  as you wish, I think:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

% Packages for maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

% Change padding of boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

% Custom title
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
}
\title{
    \textbf{Notas en Computación Cuántica}
}
\posttitle{
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \end{center}
}
\author{\large Jaime Señor}
\date{}

% Custom sectioning style
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\filcenter\Large\bfseries}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\oldsection*}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\oldsubsection*}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Sobre el operador $\boldsymbol{U_f : \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \rangle \mapsto \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \oplus f(x) \rangle}$}

\subsection{Aplicación sobre una superposición de estados $\boldsymbol{\ket{-}}$ en el qubit objetivo}

Tiene mucha relevancia la aplicación de este tipo de operadores sobre un registro de la forma $(\ket{x} \otimes \ket{-})$:

\begin{equation*}
    U_f(\ket{x}\ket{-}) = U_f \left( \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \dfrac{U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{0} \right) - U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{1} \right)}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        f(x) = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \\[15pt]
        f(x) = 1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{1} - \ket{0}}{\sqrt{2}} = - \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
    U_f(\ket{x} \ket{-}) = (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}\ket{-}
}
\end{equation*}

Lo bueno de usar el estado $\ket{-}$ es que el resultado de $f(x)$ queda codificado en el desplazamiento de fase $(-1)^{f(x)}$. Sin embargo, con el estado $\ket{+}$ no obtenemos ninguna utilidad de cara a implementar un algoritmo, porque $U_f(\ket{x}\ket{+})=\ket{x}\ket{+}$, y no aporta ninguna información sobre $f(x)$.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que según el resultado anterior, $\ket{-}$ es un autoestado de $U_f$ y se queda igual al pasar por el operador, por lo tanto podemos pasar de él al diseñar el algoritmo. A esto se le llama \textit{phase kickback}, y simplifica los algoritmos definiendo $U_f$ como

\begin{equation*}
    U_f: \ket{x} \mapsto (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}
\end{equation*}

\section{El algoritmo de Deutch}

Este algoritmo es uno de los primeros que se aprenden en computación cuántica y mola porque muestra por primera vez la gracia de la superposición cuántica.

\subsection{Enunciado del problema}

dfhgidufs

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to do. However, I don't know why but it is not working for me. The subsection is working properly, but the section header appears like normal text.

Comment: With this very code, and nothing more?

Comment: Ok sorry, now it is working properly. I don't know how I commented some lines when copying your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redefining `\section` and `\subsection`, you can use `secnumdepth`.

In order to easily center section titles, you can use `sectsty`.

Don't abuse `\boldsymbol`. It's better to use `\boldmath`.

Also, consecutive display environments should be avoided, here I use `gather*`. No blank line should precede a math display.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

% Packages for maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{sectsty}

% Change padding of boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

% Custom title
\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
}
\title{%
    \textbf{Notas en Computación Cuántica}%
}
\posttitle{%
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
    \end{center}
}
\author{\large Jaime Señor}
\date{}

% Custom sectioning style
\allsectionsfont{\boldmath}
\sectionfont{\centering\boldmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} % no numbering


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Sobre el operador 
  $U_f : \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \rangle 
    \mapsto \lvert x \rangle \lvert b \oplus f(x) \rangle$}

\subsection{Aplicación sobre una superposición de estados 
  $\ket{-}$ en el qubit objetivo}

Tiene mucha relevancia la aplicación de este tipo de operadores sobre 
un registro de la forma $(\ket{x} \otimes \ket{-})$:
\begin{gather*}
  U_f(\ket{x}\ket{-}) = U_f \left( \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - 
  \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \dfrac{U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{0} \right) - 
  U_f \left( \ket{x}\ket{1} \right)}{\sqrt{2}} = \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - 
  \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}}
\\
  \begin{cases}
    f(x) = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad
      \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} =
      \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}}
    \\[15pt]
    f(x) = 1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad
      \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{f(x)} - \ket{1 \oplus f(x)}}{\sqrt{2}} =
      \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{1} - \ket{0}}{\sqrt{2}} =
      - \ket{x} \dfrac{\ket{0} - \ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{cases}
\\
\boxed{
    U_f(\ket{x} \ket{-}) = (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}\ket{-}
}
\end{gather*}

Lo bueno de usar el estado $\ket{-}$ es que el resultado de $f(x)$ 
queda codificado en el desplazamiento de fase $(-1)^{f(x)}$. 
Sin embargo, con el estado $\ket{+}$ no obtenemos ninguna utilidad 
de cara a implementar un algoritmo, porque $U_f(\ket{x}\ket{+})=\ket{x}\ket{+}$, 
y no aporta ninguna información sobre $f(x)$.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que según el resultado anterior, $\ket{-}$ 
es un autoestado de $U_f$ y se queda igual al pasar por el operador, por 
lo tanto podemos pasar de él al diseñar el algoritmo. A esto se le llama 
\textit{phase kickback}, y simplifica los algoritmos definiendo $U_f$ como
\begin{equation*}
    U_f: \ket{x} \mapsto (-1)^{f(x)} \ket{x}
\end{equation*}

\section{El algoritmo de Deutch}

Este algoritmo es uno de los primeros que se aprenden en computación 
cuántica y mola porque muestra por primera vez la gracia de la 
superposición cuántica.

\subsection{Enunciado del problema}

dfhgidufs

\end{document}
```

[image]